# Linux alpine check musl version

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

We have docker files which based on alpine linux.
I want for the built container to check the version of the `musl` library ,
I mean run the container and and in RT check the musl version
how can I do that ?

I've tried something like

```
docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/ash
```

**and run**

```
musl -v
```

**Got**

```
/bin/ash: musl: not found
```

Answer (score 4):

musl is library, [musl package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=musl&branch=edge&arch=x86_64) provide `/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1`, `/lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1`.

You can get version by `apk info musl`.